# Como recorro una respuesta de json en c#?

Tags: c#, json, rest

Tengo una API REST que envia la siguiente respuesta en formato json y quiero recorrerlo para en cada recorrido agregar a un listview lo que recorra.

```
{
"resultado": "OK",
"datos": [
{
  "Pago": "1500.00",
  "Fecha": "2018-09-27"
},
{
  "Pago": "900.00",
  "Fecha": "2018-10-16"
}
]
}
```

La respuesta del server la deserializo asi:

```
dynamic msjdes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
```

Donde msjdes es el formato json ya en c# y aparece asi como lo puse arriba.
Como lo recorro para agregarlos como Item a un listview?
Desde ya muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que deserializar a una clase

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = "{\r\n\"resultado\": \"OK\",\r\n\"datos\": [\r\n{\r\n  \"Pago\": \"1500.00\",\r\n  \"Fecha\": \"2018-09-27\"\r\n},\r\n{\r\n  \"Pago\": \"900.00\",\r\n  \"Fecha\": \"2018-10-16\"\r\n}\r\n]\r\n}";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        foreach(var item in  result.datos){
            Console.WriteLine(item.Pago);
        }


    }
}

public class Dato
{
    public string Pago { get; set; }
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string resultado { get; set; }
    public List<Dato> datos { get; set; }
}
```

como observaras al ser tipada la deserializacion tienes acceso a las propiedades
tambien se podria hacer con el dynamic, solo que no tendras intellisense en el codigo

Comment: Funciona para mi.